# Display User Role Name on My Account Dashboard in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-roles

I have tried various solutions for this and while the code below works and do not generate any errors in the log or anything like that, I am struggling with understanding how to get the name of the user role and not the actual account username.

Here's the code I am using:

```
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
if ( is_user_logged_in()) {
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login .'';
echo '<br />';
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name .'';
}
else { wp_loginout(); }
echo '<br>';
```

I want it to display like this:

`Username:` username
`Account type:` name of role

The username and account type should be on two separate rows.
The point of the account type is because I added this:

```
add_role ( 'business', __( 'Business', 'woocommerce' ), array( 'read' => true, ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following based on your custom role "business":

```
global $current_user;

if ( $current_user > 0 ) {

    echo __('Username:') . ' ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';

    $account_type = in_array('business', $current_user->roles) ? __('Business') : __('Customer');

    echo __('Account type') . ' ' . $account_type . '<br />';
}
```

It should work as you wish.

---

**To get the role name from a user role slug:**

```
global $wp_roles;

$role = 'business';
$role_name = $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'];
```

---

If each user **has a unique user role**, you can use the following:

```
global $current_user, $wp_roles;

if ( $current_user > 0 ) {

    $role_name = $wp_roles->roles[reset($current_user->roles)]['name']; 

    echo __('Username:') . ' ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';

    echo __('Account type') . ' ' . $role_name . '<br />';
}
```

Or you can get the last user role with:

```
$role_name = $wp_roles->roles[end($current_user->roles)]['name'];
```

Comment: that works fine. But I have 6 different types of roles and I need the code to "get the role" from the system. If I have to add all the roles manually it becomes to much work when adding / removing roles.

Sorry that I was not more clear in my initial question.

Comment: @JonnyKapula  I have added an addition regarding the role name… Note: Don't forget that a user can have many roles, so if when using  `add_role()`, it adds a role to existing user roles array.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't help either. I still need to define the role myself instead of the system getting it.

Comment: @JonnyKapula The system can only **get automatically the user role name** if user has only **one unique user role**. I have added an addition in my answer at the end.

Comment: yes, in my case all roles are deleted (except for admin) and those needed are added.