# Display Current User Role in Woocommerce My account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles

I want to show the user role name with a shortcode on my custom account page. I found this code, but I couldn't use it because of my weak PHP.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'njengah_get_current_user_role'); 

function njengah_get_current_user_role() {

 if( is_user_logged_in() ) { // check if there is a logged in user 
 
         $user = wp_get_current_user(); // getting & setting the current user 
     $roles = ( array ) $user->roles; // obtaining the role 
 
        return $roles; // return the role for the current user 
 
     } else {
     
        return array(); // if there is no logged in user return empty array  
 
     }
}
```

Also, I found this, but I could not use it for the same reason:
[Display User Role Name on My Account Dashboard in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197544/display-user-role-name-on-my-account-dashboard-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wp_head` action hook is not used to print any data on the content area. It's triggered within the `<head></head>` section of the theme’s `header.php` template by the `wp_head()` function. So it won't print the value on your my-account page.

You should call the function directly within the custom my account page.

```
function njengah_get_current_user_role() {
     global $wp_roles;
     if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;
        $role = $roles[0]; 
        return translate_user_role($wp_roles->roles[$role]['name']);
     } else {
        return array();
     }
}
```

Then just call the function from your custom my account page.

```
echo njengah_get_current_user_role();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's working, but it shows the role slug; I need the role name.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check again. You can use `translate_user_role($wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'])` to get role name. Hope it works.